# Fn key switches on and off, randomly

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

My <kbd>F</kbd> keys sometimes require the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to be used, and then later at a seemingly random time they don't. For example, Guake sometimes requires me to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to use it when normally its just <kbd>F12</kbd>.

When the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is required by the <kbd>F</kbd> keys, none of my volume buttons on the keyboard continue to work either. I have played around with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> setting in bios but I did little to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: 13.04 but I had the same issue on 12.04. Running


Toshiba E300